# What is wrong with this loop

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using a loop condition to check if there is null value in the columns, then remove it.

[-Original author](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126155254/http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/08/11/removing-columns-in-datatable.aspx)

```
[STart:]
    For i As Integer = counter To dt1.Columns.Count - 1
      For x As Integer = 0 To dt1.Rows.Count - 1
        if some condition then
            something = true
        else
                something = false
            counter = counter + 1
                Goto [Start]
        end if
      Next
    
      If something = true
        dt1.Columns.Remove(dt1.Columns(i))
        i -= 1
      End If
    Next
  End If
```

Sometimes it runs correctly and sometimes even though when `i` becomes greater than `(dt.columns.count - 1)`, it still executes the for loop and throws an error that there is no column with that index. I must be missing something here but I'm not able to debug the issue.

Do you guys find anything wrong with this code?

Comment: Not sure why you got down-voted here. This is what this site is about. Posting questions to a network of fellow programmers. +1 from me.

Comment: I'm also not sure :(. May be they are great programmers who do not like programmers like me making mistakes and trying to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `dt1.Columns.Count` is evaluated at the very beginning of the for loop. It does not get re-evaluated each time the loop runs.

So when you remove a column in the body of the loop it causes the end condition of the loop to go wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that the i-loop only evaluates the stopping value once.

Answer (score 2):

Its a bad idea to alter the object on which you are looping.  This might be having an effect in some cases.  I would copy your datatable - loop on the first table and alter the second.

Also, have you seen the [Select method on datatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select(VS.71).aspx)?  It might make this search for null values easier then embedded loops (loop on the columns and call select)

```
Dim DRs AS DataRow() = dt1.Select(dt1.Columns(i).ColumnName " IS NULL")
If DRs.Count > 0 Then
    '' // do something
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are deleting in your outer loop, don't rely upon the reevalution of dt1.Columns.Count

Further, try counting down instead of up (because if you delete a column in your count down, it won't affect what the next valid index is)

Something like this for your outer loop:

warning: I'm a c# developer, my syntax for the vb for loop might be off
read: I want to loop down from the highest column number down to column 0

```
'' // leave no question as to how often count will be evaluated.
'' //  we will ensure it happens only once:
Dim colmns as int = dt1.Columns.Count - 1
for i as integer = columns to 0 step -1
 '' // your logic goes here 
 '' // DON'T manualy modify the value of i -- it will always be right.
Next
```

This works better in reverse.  Think about it like this:
say I have 4 columns, and I am on #3.
If # 3 is non-null, I will leave it alone, and my next column is #2
If #3 is null, I will delete it, but my next columns is still #2, and I'm still finished when I get to zero.